# Develop a model for determining the optimal production schedule in a manufacturing facility

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, constraints, operations-research

I have to formulate (linearly) the following problem mathematically:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

What I tried:

---

**1. Variables**

Let $x_{ijk} = 1$ if, in month k, product i should be made in production line j, where $i=1-3$, $j=1-2$ and $k=1-6$.

Let $d_{ik}$ represent how much of product i should be made in month k.

Let $c_{ij}$ represent unit production cost of producing product i in production line j.

Let $p_{ij}$ represent production rate of producing product i in production line j.

Let $s_{ij}$ represent cost of switching...*to* product i?  or *from*?

---

**2. Objective Function**

Min

$$z = 0.5\sum_{k=1}^{6} x_{1,j,k} + 0.35\sum_{k=1}^{6} x_{2,j,k} + 0.45\sum_{k=1}^{6} x_{3,j,k} + \sum_i \sum_j \sum_k c_{ij} p_{ij} x_{ijk}$$

$$- \sum_i \sum_j \sum_k s_{ijk} y_{ijk} x_{ijk}$$

where $y_{ijk} = 1$ if, in month k, production line j switches (to or from?) product i and $0$ otherwise.

Or is that the other way around?

---

**3. Constraints:**

For all k, all j and all i,

$$\text{Constraints} \ 1-36: \sum_{m=1}^{k} p_{ij}x_{ijm} - d_{i,0} \ge \sum_{m=1}^{k} d_{im}$$

$$\text{Constraints} \ 37-72: x_{ijk} \le My_{ijk}$$

where $d_{i,0}$ represents how much of product i is in the initial inventory.

---

**Where did I go wrong?**

---

Other questions:

---

1. To what is $s_{ijk}$ supposed to refer? Cost of switching *to* product i?  *from*?

Does it matter?

2. Is my $y_{ijk}$ wrong?

---

From Chapter 3 [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ABIU1apSS8r3CbA&id=5EA51B764D593198%212679&cid=5EA51B764D593198).